# Page redirect not working PHP

Tags: php, shopping-cart

Im trying to redirect my user when they click "Empty Cart".
The redirect is working with my "Add to cart" but not for "Empty cart". Any ideas would be great.

In my main .php file i set the current url as seen

```
$current_url = base64_encode("http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]");
```

Then below is my cartAction.php file that handles actions such as "Add to cart" and "Empty cart"

```
<?php
session_start();
include_once 'config.php';

//add item in shopping cart
if(isset($_POST["add"])) {
    $product_id = $_POST["product_id"]; //product id
    $return_url = base64_decode($_POST["return_url"]); //return url
    $qty = $_POST["qty"];
    $product = $mysqli->query("SELECT product_name, unit_price, unit_quantity FROM products WHERE product_id = '$product_id'");
    $obj = $product->fetch_object();

    if(!isset($_SESSION['products'])) {
        $_SESSION['products'] = array();
    }

    if(array_key_exists($product_id, $_SESSION['products'])) {
        $_SESSION['products'][$product_id]['qty'] += $qty;
        //redirect back to original page
        header('Location:'.$return_url);
    }
    else {
        $_SESSION['products'][$product_id] = array('name' => $obj->product_name, 'price' => $obj->unit_price, 'unit' => $obj->unit_quantity, 'qty' => $qty); 
    }

    //redirect back to original page
    header('Location:'.$return_url);
}

//empty cart by distroying current session
if(isset($_POST["emptycart"]))
{
    $return_url = base64_decode($_POST["return_url"]); //return url
    session_destroy();
    header('Location:'.$return_url);
}
?>
```

Comment: Are you sure that `$_POST['return_url']` is set? Try to `var_dump` it and check its value.

Comment: `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` at the top of your php.  Guarantee you'll have something useful.

Comment: First, what is "doesn't work"? The button doesn't do anything; you get an error; the "white screen of death" etc? Also, you could test if `session_destroy()` doesn't mess with `header`. Otherwise, are you sure the program flow even reaches the bottom `if` branch?

Comment: This is a known phenomenon. Some people recommend using `unset` instead of `session_destroy`, others think you should add `exit()` after the `header` command. Anyway, do some googling - I found this in 2 minutes.

Comment: Are you deleting the entries from the shopping cart when you confirm they clicked empty cart?

Comment: @Devon thank you for that input it helped me sort it out immediately. As Ofir Baruch suggested my '$_POST['return_url'] was not set properly. 
As opposed to 'nhee', I haven't had the need of using 'exit()' if the header is set properly the redirect should work. 
Thanks to all who commented !

Answer (score 0):

"Are you sure that $_POST['return_url'] is set? Try to var_dump it and check its value. " @OfirBaruch

"error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1); at the top of your php. Guarantee you'll have something useful." @Devon

Above are the appropriate answers/approaches to the problem.

Comment: You should edit your question and put those findings in. That way, we'll know that all the details to the problem are in one place. Or wait, do you mean your problem is solved now?